# Execute program as non-admin from within a java application running as admin

Tags: java, security, administrator

I have the following scenario:

An advanced java application X requires admin privileges to work, and also provides an API for extension support, extensions are programs that can be loaded into the application itself.

So you can "install" a sub-program Y in X.
X will then open Y with some command line arguments within the application itself (with java ProcessBuilder & Runtime)

Currently X and Y both run with admin privileges, but Y shouldn't and I see that as a security issue. Is there any approach on how I can fix this? There unfortunately is no way of running X as a non-administrator.

Ideally, a solution would exist that works cross-platform

Comment: "What other user?" And that's not a joke comment: what other user? Tons of windows users only ever run on an account that has admin rights and there _is_ no regular user, so what do you actually hope to do here if you want to truly have a cross-platform solution? If it's to secure your external calls so that unknown externals can't run with admin rights, the _real_ solution is to not run unknown externals, and to verify all known externals before you do run them.

Comment: the program X comes for both Mac, Linux & Windows, and they all need to be run as admin because it needs to edit the hosts file & run another program that requires elevated permissions

The goal would be to have Y not be run with those same elevated permissions, because I feel like people could just install viruses and would never even have a popup or something come up which you normally have when something is asking for elevated permissions.

Comment: Right, but what I'm trying to tell you is that most windows installs don't _have_ a non-admin user. Their default account _is an admin_ and they'd have to have gone out of their way to downgrade their account. So if you want something secure, relying on "a non-admin account" is _not_ going to work, and instead you are responsible for making sure your code verifies that what it's about to call is safe to call with admin rights, because you get no choice: no matter what you do, there is no non-admin account that'll run it.